# Can't find element when trying to send keyevent

Tags: testing, ember.js, keyboard-events

In my integration test I can't seem to get a `keyEvent` to work at all. Specifically, I can't get the `keyEvent` to find any elements to register the `keyEvent` on at all.

```
test('Command + A selects all tags', function(assert){
  server.create('tag',{
    firstName: 'George',
    lastName: 'Washington'
  });
  server.create('tag',{
    firstName: 'Abe',
    lastName: 'Lincoln'
  });
  visit('/tags');
  keyEvent('#ember-testing', 'keydown', '65',{metaKey: true});
  andThen(()=>{
    assert.equal( find('.tag-component').length, 2 );
  });
});
```

I keep getting `Uncaught Error: Element #ember-testing not found.`

```
Ember      :    2.18.2
Ember Data :    2.18.2
jQuery     :    3.3.1
```

Comment: Put a `debugger` statement right before your `keyEvent` line, and then run your test in the browser with `ember test --server`.  What elements do you see available?  If there's nothing there, your test isn't properly starting the app

Comment: @dwenzel I see the `#ember-testing` element but the rest of the app is not there. I also added this `debugger` into some of the other tests I have after the `visit()` statements and I similarly don't see any other app elements. However, these other tests all run just fine.

Comment: I think `visit` may be asynchronous, so you'll need to add another `andThen` right after it. Or consider using async/await instead of `andThen`